# Facebook Comment Export to my Blog?

Tags: facebook, rss, facebook-wall

I have a blog and use Social RSS to send the feeds to facebook Fan page Wall. When some one comments on that. i want that to be captured and published on my blog. will that be possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use graph api, keep checking the last comment time on that post, if its greater than the one on the blog, pull all the comments and publish on the blog.
Cant think of a way for real time update.

Comment: how to pull the comments from facebook fan page ?

Comment: First authenticate using oauth, then get post id for your post,will be in the form of pageId_someNumber.Then keep quering for the last updated time for the post, if it changes query for the comments on the post.(plz refer to page and post sections in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ )

Comment: Thanks a lot.. sorry for the late reply :D